Time stretching / slowing down part of a MIDI file
Let's say I have a MIDI file of a solo piano performance. There's a small section in the middle of the piece that's played a tad too fast and I'd like to slow down this part slightly (while not changing what comes before/after it).
What would be the best way of doing this? In the DAW that I use (an old version of Mixcraft), I can't find any easy way to do it.

If you're adventurous, you could find the tempo event at that point (if there is one) in a hex editor, indicated by FF 51 03 followed by the number of microseconds per quarter note, stored in three bytes. Then lower that amount and save the file. (Make a backup first.) Perhaps you could even insert a tempo event (six bytes in all) in your hex editor, if you can find where it should go (perhaps because you recognize a few notes).

Realistically, if your DAW doesn't have a MIDI timestretch function, get one that does. Cakewalk is free. I think it does timestretch. Cakewalk

I don't know Mixcraft, but I would be quite surprised if it didn't provide the possibility of setting tempo changes, even in an older version, since it's a basic aspect of any decent DAW. Basically, you should just add a new metronome mark where the "small section" begins, then add a new one where it ends. Take your time and study the documentation to find out how.

Consider using tempo map, to adjust tempo of various parts of the project, possibly even with smooth transitions. I would think it is a basic functionality of most DAWs and MIDI sequencers. I found some instructions to adjust tempo in Mixcraft, but I don't have experience with it.
Adjusting tempo map is less destructive than modifying the lengths of MIDI notes, which I presume is what Laurence means by "timestretch". The former might be better for small adjustments of tempo while preserving the original feel of the recording; the latter might work better for more aggressive editing, possibly including quantization or manual alignment of selected notes.
